How do I access the orignalId in a webform results export form?
Seems like I never run out of compound objects that seem impregnable, lol!
I am hooking webform_custom_submit. I only want the function to execute if the originalId, which is the name of the webform which results are being requested, is a specific value.
The only place I've found that contains the originalId is:
$form_state
  build_info
    callback_object
      submissionExporter
        webform
          originalId

I can access $form_state, of course.
I access build_info with $bi = $form_state->getBuildInfo();
I seem to only be able to access callback_object with $co = (array)$bi
At this point, $co is an array:
$callback_object = array[10]
  requestStack = null
  configFactory = Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory
  routeMatch = null
  _serviceIds = array[0]
  _entityStorages = array[0]
  loggerFactory = null
  messenger = null
  redirectDestination = null
  stringTranslation = Drupal\Core\String\Translation\TranslationManager
  submissionExporter = Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionExporter

I've tried to cast array on submissionExporter, but I get null.
How do I get to originalId?

Given that there are no getters defined and I cannot make changes to the underlying classes, the way to go is via Reflection. The following results in being able to obtain the original ID. In case I wasn't clear, I'm working with the form used to obtain webform submissions downloads. I don't want its form ID. I needed the ID of the webform for which submissions are being requested.
  $callbackObject = $buildinfo['callback_object'];

  // Step 1: Access `submissionExporter` from `callback_object`
  $reflectionCallbackObject = new ReflectionClass(get_class($callbackObject));
  $submissionExporterProperty = $reflectionCallbackObject->getProperty('submissionExporter');
  $submissionExporterProperty->setAccessible(true); // Make the property accessible
  $submissionExporter = $submissionExporterProperty->getValue($callbackObject);

  // Step 2: Access `webform` from `submissionExporter`
  $reflectionSubmissionExporter = new ReflectionClass(get_class($submissionExporter));
  $webformProperty = $reflectionSubmissionExporter->getProperty('webform');
  $webformProperty->setAccessible(true); // Make the property accessible
  $webform = $webformProperty->getValue($submissionExporter);

  // Step 3: Access `originalId` from `webform`
  $reflectionWebform = new ReflectionClass(get_class($webform));
  $originalIdProperty = $reflectionWebform->getProperty('originalId');
  $originalIdProperty->setAccessible(true); // Make the property accessible
  $originalId = $originalIdProperty->getValue($webform);

